# Can't Scrape Input Value from dolartoday.com with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I want to scrape the `value` of element `#result` with:

```
 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto('https://dolartoday.com');
      await console.log(page.evaluate(() => document.getElementById('result')));

      await browser.close();
    })();
```

But it still logs the following error:

```
(node:74908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
at Promise.then (/Volumes/DATOS/Dropbox/workspaces/dolar-today/server/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/NavigatorWatcher.js:71:21)
at <anonymous>
(node:74908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:74908) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: `Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, you are attempting to use the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) operator on [`console.log()`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args) (a synchronous function), rather than on [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) (an asynchronous function).

You are also attempting to return a Page DOM element to the Node.js environment, which will not work because [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) is expecting a [serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description) return value.

If you would like to return the `value` of the `#result` element on the web page, you should rewrite your logic as follows:

```
console.log(await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementById('result').value));
```

Furthermore, the navigation time has exceeded 30000 milliseconds (the default maximum). You can expand the maximum navigation time using the `timeout` option in your [`page.goto()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) function:

```
await page.goto('https://dolartoday.com', {
  timeout: 60000,
});
```

You can also reject unnecessary resources from loading in the web page using [`page.setRequestInterception()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue) and [`page.on('request')`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener). This will make your web page load much faster:

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on('request', request => {
  if (['image', 'stylesheet', 'font'].indexOf(request.resourceType()) !== -1) {
    request.abort();
  } else {
    request.continue();
  }
});
```

**Your final program should look something like this:**

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  page.on('request', request => {
    if (['image', 'stylesheet', 'font'].indexOf(request.resourceType()) !== -1) {
      request.abort();
    } else {
      request.continue();
    }
  });

  await page.goto('https://dolartoday.com', {
    timeout: 60000,
  });

  console.log(await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementById('result').value));

  await browser.close();
})();
```